# Highchart tooltip position to be fixed

Tags: highcharts

I HV multi line chart, I want the shared tooltip to be at the top of the graph ( so that it doesn't covers up the space of graph) , but I want it to have fixed 'y'
And x coordinate to be Free.
So that user can hover over the graph and the tooltip comes at the top of that point ( x coordinate).

Is there a way where I can fix only the y coordinate of the tooltip position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `tooltip.positioner` function.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        return { x: point.plotX, y: 15 };
    },
    shadow: false,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nt9x5tjj/

The callback receives a `point` object that contains `plotX` and `plotY` positions.  Fix the `y` value to some number and return `point.plotX` as the `x` value.

Comment: Thank you for your instant help.

Comment: How do I make sure the tooltip comes at top of the graph? Coz changing the y to any values, still the tooltip is in mid way n cover ing the graph

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you see the tooltip in the jsfiddle mid way on the graph?

Comment: No it's fine, it was some css issue.

Comment: I have one issue though, my custom tootlip is working fine but not for last point. It seems to go out of the chart area, where earlier ( without custom tooltip) it used to adjust properly for last point. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can call the default positioned to get the adjusted numbers and then override your x position